# Not able to read Excel 2013 file with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel in perl

Tags: excel, perl

I have a simple piece of code,that is not loading the excel file. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong :

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse("test.xlsx");
if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    print("Unable to load workbook \n");
}
```

I also tried running with the full path of the file.
The test.xlsx is an Excel 2013 file
I am running in Windows with Perl 5.14.2 and the file is in the same folder as the .pl file.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#DESCRIPTION):

> The Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module can be used to read information from Excel 95-2003 binary files.
>
> The module cannot read files in the Excel 2007 Open XML XLSX format. See the [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) module instead.